# Modal dialog freezes the whole application

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I use wxpython altogether with matplotlib backend on an ubuntu machine. I would like to connect my matplotlib canvas to a button_press_event that pops up a wxpython modal dialog. When the modal dialog pops up, the whole application gets frozen. This problem does not occur on a windows machine. Here is a snippet that typically reproduces the problem.

```
import wx

from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class SettingDialog(wx.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, title="Modal dialog")


class PlotterFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title="Frame with matplotlib canvas"):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, title)

        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=None)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasWxAgg(self, -1, self.figure )
        self.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.on_click)


    def on_click(self, event=None):
        d = SettingDialog(self)
        d.ShowModal()
        d.Destroy()  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    f = PlotterFrame(None)
    f.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Would you have any idea of what is wrong with my code ?

PS0 : The problem is that the dialog window is also frozen, like all the applications in the desktop wich do not react anymore. the only way to escape is to switch to another desktop using the keyboard

PS1 : with a very common example like http://eli.thegreenplace.net/files/prog_code/wx_mpl_bars.py.txt 
the problem also appear, I conclude so that, this issue is a bug on linux (here ubuntu 12.04) for the following libs version :
 wx.**version** : '2.8.12.1'
matplotlib.**version** : '1.1.1rc'

Comment: isn't that the point of modal dialogues (to block the rest of the program)?

Comment: The problem is that the dialog window is also frozen, like all the application in the desktop wich do not react anymore. the only way to escape is to switch to another desktop using the keyboard ...

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a modal dialog is that it freezes the application while the dialog is in its modal state. If you don't want the application to freeze, then don't show the dialog modally.

Comment: The problem is that the dialog window is also frozen, like all the application in the desktop wich do not react anymore. the only way to escape is to switch another desktop using keyboard ...

Comment: There could be some odd interaction between matplotlib and wx that I'm unaware of. You should probably ask on the wxPython and matplotlib mailing lists.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem too, on several different Linux systems. None of the various mentioned resources seem to be describing exactly the same as this problem. After some investigation, it seems that something is locking up when you try to show a modal dialog **before** the mouse release event fires in the Matplotlib FigureCanvas.

Once I realized that, the solution is very simple. Your event handler should become:

```
def on_click(self, event=None):
    try:
        event.guiEvent.GetEventObject().ReleaseMouse()
    except:
        pass
    d = SettingDialog(self)
    d.ShowModal()
    d.Destroy()
```

One issue that could complicate the code is that not all matplotlib events have the same structure. So if this had been a 'pick_event' handler, you would instead do

```
event.mouseevent.guiEvent.GetEventObject().ReleaseMouse()
```

Check http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html for the key to which Event types are passed in by which matplotlib events.